# What's going on with \> and \< in strings?

Tags: string-manipulation, boxes, input

What exactly do `\>` and `\<` do in Mathematica strings (e.g. `"ab\>c"`)?

They sure exhibit some weird behavior! If you evaluate a string containing either of these, it *completely disappears* from the string: `"ab\>c"` evaluates to `"abc"`.

And this isn't some formatting trickery: `StringLength["ab\>c"]` evaluates to `3`; indeed, `"a\<b\>c" == "abc"` (and even `"a\<b\>c" === "abc"`) evaluates to `True`.

Viewing the box structure of the input and output with <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>, in addition to reconfirming that the outputs are *exactly* the same, perhaps shows us a clue: evaluating `"abc"` and viewing the box structure of the output yields

```
Cell[BoxData["\<\"abc\"\>"], "Output", ...]
```

(Oddly enough, viewing the box structure for the *input* cell containing `"abc"` yields `Cell[BoxData["\"\<abc\>\""], "Input", ...]`—the escaped quotes, `\"`, are now outside the `\<`, `\>` "brackets".)

Notice that these seem to be exclusively "string-enclosing brackets": viewing the box structure of `3` yields `Cell[BoxData["3"], ...]`

But what actually is their purpose? When does Mathematica use them, and maybe more importantly, why? Neither the documentation for `BoxData` nor `String` seem to offer any clues—searching the documentation for `\>` doesn't yield any results, either.

Comment: Those are reserved characters used to build box expression. If you need a "\>" literal, you need to escape them: `"ab\\>c"` or `"ab\\<c"` work as you would expect.

Comment: I figured they had something to do with boxes. But I'm curious as to *how* exactly they're used to build box expressions—they don't appear anywhere in the documentation, that I can see.

Comment: I have marked this as a duplicate.  Please review that question (linked in the banner at the top of yours), and let me know if you agree.

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you! I tried searching stackexchange for "\>" and "\<", but I expect the search function itself excludes these characters, as nothing came up. :)